# .htaccess - rewrite get parameters with their values

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I can get this line to `rewrite` the url:

```bsh
RewriteRule ^home$ /?filter=top&start=0 [L]
```

And in this case, I can get my `$_GET` array in `php`.

But I cant extract `query params` to put them on left-side rewrited url with:

```bsh
RewriteRule ^home\/([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)$ /?filter=$1&start=$2 [L]
```

am I missing something?
I hope that in the second example, even after rewriting urls, I can retreive `$_GET` array.

Comment: The slashes don't require escaping, but it should not be harmful  What is your full set of rewrite rules? Please post them all in the order they appear in your .htaccess

Comment: What resides at `/`? That should look something like `index.php?filter=$1&start=$2 [L]`

Comment: What is your url? What you've got now will only match something like `/home/foo/123`.

Comment: @MarcB that's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What _does_ it do instead of work as expected? The document root-relative path `/` is permitted according to the docs, but more commonly you'll see the filename specified as `index.php`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski it gives a 404 error instead. even with the `index.php` instead of `/`, it doesnt change.

Comment: Ok, try changing it to `index.php?filter=$1&start=$2` as already suggested, and failing that, post any other rewrite rules you have.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I commented all the rewrite rules present on this `.htaccess` joomla file. The 404 error remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `404 error` was caused by `joomla sef plugin`, when I deactivate it the rule works!